# Codeigniter and jQuery - Validate form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, codeigniter, validation

I do lots of my own coding with Codeigniter+jQuery combo. My current project has lot's of different kind of inputs, and when data is different, I have to handle it differently. One field can be email field, one field can be number field that has to allow only numbers and comma etc. You got the point.

I made really easy example how I have been doing things. So when submit is pressed I check every input's data with regex match and if something is wrong, then it will change color of that input, and inform on some field that whats wrong. Quite simple.

This method works, but when I have lots of inputs it gets really messy and hard to maintain, and what I mean by that is that I have to have PHP fallback if user have disabled javascript. So I have same checks on jQuery and PHP side.

Other thing is security. I think that I'm almost too paranoid about exploits/XSS attacks, and I often remove all unwanted characters with regex and after that i check with other regex that if that remaining data is valid.

I would be grateful if somebody could tell if there is better way to achieve this data handling/validating between Codeigniter and jQuery.

**application/controllers/example.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('example_view');
  }

  public function jquery()
  {
    echo "Username: ". $this->input->post('userName');
    echo "userAge: ". $this->input->post('userAge');
    echo "userEmail: ". $this->input->post('userEmail');
  }
}
?>
```

**application/views/example_view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="status"></div> <br />

    <form id="userForm">
      <label for="userName">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" /> <br />

      <br />

      <label for="userAge">Age:</label>
      <input type="text" name="userAge" id="userAge" /> </br >

      <br />

      <label for="userEmail">E-Mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" /> </br >

      </br >

      <input type="submit" name="sendData" value="Send it" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>


<script>
$("#userForm").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var error = 0;

    if($("#userForm").match('/regexp_here/'))
    {
      $("#userName").addClass('alert');
      error++;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#userName").removeClass('alert');
    }

    if($("#userAge").match('/regexp_here/'))
    {
      $("#userAge").addClass('alert');
      error++;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#userAge").removeClass('alert');
    }

    if($("#userEmail").match('/regexp_here/'))
    {
      $("#userEmail").addClass('alert');
      error++;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#userEmail").removeClass('alert');
    }

    if(error == 0)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'example/jquery/',
        data: { 
          userName: userName, 
          userAge: userAge, 
          userEmail: userEmail
        },
        success:function(data) 
        {
          $("status").html(data);
        },
        error:function() 
        {
          $("status").html("Well, it was error...");
        }
      });
    }
    else { }
});
</script>
```

Comment: why dont you use some jquery validation plugin for UI, recently I integrated this in my codeigniter project.
http://parsleyjs.org/

Comment: You should show us your validation code. I think you need to do both client-side validation (for user experience) and server-side with CI (for security).Since you are using html5 why dont you take advantage of it's input types? Then most browsers would at least do a little client side validation? See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp